# Simpleform Bootstrap 3 radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

Does Simpleform have support for Bootstrap3 radio button?

I tried with the config custom wrapper below but this doesn't seem to work very well.

```
config.wrappers :radio_buttons, tag: 'div', class: "form-group", error_class: "has-error" do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :label, { class: "control-label col-lg-4" }
    b.wrapper :tag => 'div', class: "col-lg-8" do |ba|
      ba.wrapper :tag => 'div', class: 'checkbox' do |bb|
        bb.use :input, { class: 'uniform', label: false }
        bb.use :label_text { label: false }
      end
    end
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :p, class: "help-block" }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: "help-block text-danger" }
  end
```

What could be change in this code to support something like below?

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <div class="radio"><span class="checked"><input class="uniform" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="option1" checked=""></span></div>Checked
                                    radio
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.checkbox -->
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <div class="radio"><span><input class="uniform" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="option2"></span></div>Unchecked
                                    radio
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.checkbox -->
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <div class="radio disabled"><span class="checked"><input class="uniform" type="radio" name="optionsRadios2" value="option3" checked="" disabled=""></span></div>
                                    Disabled checked radio
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.checkbox -->
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <div class="radio disabled"><span><input class="uniform" type="radio" name="optionsRadios2" value="option4" disabled=""></span></div>
                                    Disabled unchecked radio
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.checkbox -->
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I really don't think you should be putting a radio class inside of a checkbox class. Why are you mixing checkbox and radio classes? If you look at the [bootstrap css example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), you'll see this:

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
    Option two can be something else and selecting it will deselect option one
  </label>
</div>
```

But anyway, this should just come down to css. What's your application.css (or application.scss) file look like? Are you importing/requiring bootstrap as sort of your default css? Also, what does your form itself look like?